# Reusing thread and UdpClient for sending and receiving on same port

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, socket

The working and functional code below is a simplification of a real test application I've written. It acts as a client which asynchronously sends UDP data from a local endpoint and listens for an echo'ed response from a server implemented elsewhere.

The requirements are:

1. Send and listen on the same port number;
2. The port number must be able to change (simulates data coming in from various 
   sources)

The program does what I want, but I have doubts about its correctness. Specifically regarding the class members of `listenThread` and `udpClient` which are reused when the port number changes.  Are they implemented, closed and cleaned-up correctly.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace cs_console
{
    class Tester
    {
        public void Send(string message, int localPort)
        {
            PrepareClient(localPort);
            SendBytes(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
        }

        private void PrepareClient(int localPort)
        {
            if (localEP == null || localEP.Port != localPort)
            {
                localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(localHost), localPort);
                listenThread = new Thread(StartListening);
                listenThread.Start();
            }
        }

        private void StartListening()
        {
            udpClient = new UdpClient();
            udpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
            udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            udpClient.Client.Bind(localEP);

            var s = new UdpState(localEP, udpClient);
            currentAsyncResult = udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), s);
        }

        private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            if (ar == currentAsyncResult)
            {
                UdpClient c = (UdpClient)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).c;
                IPEndPoint e = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e;

                Byte[] buffer = c.EndReceive(ar, ref e);
                if (buffer.Length > 0)
                    System.Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));

                UdpState s = new UdpState(e, c);
                currentAsyncResult = udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), s);
            }
        }

        private void SendBytes(byte[] messageData)
        {
            var sender = new UdpClient();
            sender.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
            sender.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            sender.Client.Bind(localEP);
            sender.Send(messageData, messageData.Length, remoteEP);
            sender.Close();
        }

        private static string localHost = "10.27.21.109";
        private IPEndPoint localEP = null;
        private IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(localHost), 11000);
        private Thread listenThread = null;
        private UdpClient udpClient = null;
        private IAsyncResult currentAsyncResult = null;

        private class UdpState : Object
        {
            public UdpState(IPEndPoint e, UdpClient c) { this.e = e; this.c = c; }
            public IPEndPoint e;
            public UdpClient c;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tester tester = new Tester();
            int localPort = 2532;
            while (true)
            {
                ++localPort;
                var message = Console.ReadLine();
                tester.Send(message, localPort);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is as compact a working example as I could make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I find a better naming convention for private fields on a class is `_PascalCase` or `_camelCase`. This makes it easy to see whether you are using a field or a local variable.
2. It is completely unnecessary to create a new `Thread` to call `StartListening`. The thread will terminate once `udpClient.BeginReceive()` has been called as this is async. You might as well call `StartListening()` directly in `PrepareClient()`.
3. [`UdpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `IDisposable` and should therefor be disposed when not needed anymore. You do not clean up the existing `UdpClient` at all.

   [The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662553/how-to-abort-sockets-beginreceive) indicates that when you call `Dispose` or `Close` on a socket then the callback is invoked but will throw an `ObjectDisposedException` when calling `EndReceive` . Because you are storing the `currentAsyncResult` you can probably get around this by changing `StartListening()` to this:

   ```
   private readonly object _clientLock = new object();

   private void StartListening()
   {
       lock (_clientLock)
       {
           if (udpClient != null)
           {
               currentAsyncResult = null;
               updClient.Dispose();
           }
           udpClient = new UdpClient();
           udpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
           udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
           udpClient.Client.Bind(localEP);

           var s = new UdpState(localEP, udpClient);
           currentAsyncResult = udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), s);
       }
   }
   ```

   Plus you should lock the inner block of your receive callback. This should ensure that you don't kill the client in the middle of receiving.